# Computing the mean of a Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability

[image]

I am trying to compute the mean of a Gaussian random variable with $X(μ,σ^2)$
I am stuck on this integral as it seems I cannot use integration by parts nor substitution.

I searched on other questions, but found only other techniques to compute the mean in different ways.

Comment: The integral above is not the expression for the mean of a Gaussian. In front we want $\frac{y}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\sigma}$, not $\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma^2}$. However, if you want the integral of the OP, the substitution $y-\mu=u$ will do it.

Comment: Thanks! I messed up on the calculations. P.S. This was part of a split integral for the Gaussian.

Comment: You are welcome. If there remain difficulties, as long as no "answer" is given you can feel free to modify your question to the one you really intended. If you do, please indicate where the difficulty lies, and what you have done.

Comment: The question has been answered, this integral becomes 0 and combined with the other part of the integral $u$ is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use U-substitution. The integral evaluates to zero as desired.